# HttpClient keeps receiving bad request

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having a hard time resolving my Bad Request responses from a REST api when I'm creating a client using C#.  I tested the REST api using Fiddler 2 and executing it there, but when I'm creating the same thing programmatically I get 400 response.  Here is my Fiddler composer test:

URL:

```
https://<third-party-rest-client>/api/v2/job
```

Here are my Headers

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
icSessionId: PomCSBCVU4VgXCJ5    
Content-Length: 123
```

And here is the body I'm sending a POST request with

```
{
"@type": "job",
"taskId":"0000G20G000000000002",
"taskName":"TestReplication",
"taskType":"DRS",
"callbackURL":""
}
```

This POST comes back with a 200 response and a response body, which is perfect, but when I try to simulate the same thing in C# with this code:

```
public JobResponse RunJob(JobRequest jobRequest)
    {
        try
        {
            client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(loggedUser.serverUrl + "/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("icSessionId", icSessionId);

            string message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jobRequest);
            message = message.Insert(1, "\"@type\": \"job\",");
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/v2/job", message).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JobResponse>().Result;
            }
            else
            {
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This comes back as a 400.  Does anybody have any ideas what's wrong with my code?

Comment: What are you getting from your Console.WriteLines? What comes back in the 400 body?

Comment: Does the API accept Uppercase JSON values? The HttpClient sends  uppercase fieldnames by default.

Comment: you don't need to serialize your object. You can pass it direct to `client.PostAsJsonAsync`. Also, on your `loggedUser.serverUrl` do you have something like `"http://servername"`. You can see some examples at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: @SimonC - I get html back that looks like this:

    <html><head><title>Error</title></head><body><h4>URI: /saas/api/v2/job</h4><h4>Status Code: 400</h4></body></html>

Also, the api accepts the lowercase values I showed.  Are you saying that HttpClient is changing them to capitalized values?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the issue I was having.  It seems that Serializing my JSON object into a string first, then posting it with `PostAsJsonAsync` was leaving all of the escape (\) characters in my object, which was why I received the Bad Request.

The problem here was my first key/value pair in my JSON object had a key with the @ symbol in it.  If I try to just `PostAsJsonAsync` with the object, I lost the @ symbol, which gave me a Bad Request also.

What I ended up doing was Serializing the object into a string as seen above, then I converted it the a Byte Array and then created a new `ByteArrayContent` object passing in my byte array, adding the `ContentType` attribute to the `ByteArrayContent` Headers, then using `PostAsync` instead of `PostAsJsonAsync`.  This worked perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
public JobResponse RunInformaticaJob(JobRequest jobRequest)
    {
        try
        {
            client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("icSessionId", icSessionId);

            string message = JSONSerializer.Serialize(jobRequest);
            message = message.Insert(1, "\"@type\": \"job\",");
            byte[] messageBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            var content = new ByteArrayContent(messageBytes);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            var response = client.PostAsync(loggedUser.serverUrl + "/api/v2/job", content).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JobResponse>().Result;
            }
            else
            {
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Issue resolved!

Comment: @MohitShah - Thanks!

Comment: Why is this still a problem! I was getting HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name. I just fought with this issue for 3 hours trying to figure out which header was wrong. And it wasn't even the header, but the Body....

Comment: Wow, thanks @JohnGrabanski your comment was super useful in me identifying what was causing the 400 - thanks so much!

Comment: I had an object that had a UserAgent string as one of the properties - that string basically ensured failure trying to conver to JSON then restore back as the object.  This solution, converting the JSON to ByteArrayContent, then using PostAsync, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 29):

In my case examining the content of `result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` had the cause of the problem informing of some missing parameters and some parameters with invalid values. Corrected and it's working now.

Comment: So what you had correct? in general, result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result won't make content corrupt.

Comment: The `result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` also point me the error I had. In my case, it told me that I wrongly use apostrophes instead of double quote for members, which lead in an incorrect json syntax.