# Response 400 on the post of httpclient in dotnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am wrote the code to POST from my web application but it is sending 400 bad request.
See the my controller class:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAgent(AgentCreateDto agentCreateDto)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44331/api/");
                var responseTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync("Agent/CreateAgent", agentCreateDto);
                responseTask.Wait();

                var result = responseTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var newAgentAdd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AgentCreateDto>(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    var newAgent = newAgentAdd;
                    TempData["SuccessMessage"] = $"Agent {newAgent.FirstName} was successfully created.";
                    return RedirectToAction("AgentLists");
                    //return RedirectToAction("GetAgentById", new { AgentId = newAgent.usersId});
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Here is below the problem image please see for the reference.
[image: Exception for the post httpClientRequest]

Here is api code for that I am send the request:

```
[HttpPost("CreateAgent")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAgent([FromForm]AgentCreateDto agentCreateDto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid model object");
            }
           
                if (agentCreateDto.ProfileImage != null)
                {
                    string uniqueFileName = UploadProfileImage(agentCreateDto.ProfileImage);
                    agentCreateDto.ProfileNewImage = uniqueFileName;
                }
                var createAgent = await _userService.CreateAgent(agentCreateDto);
                //_logger.LogInformation($"User added to the for file test. ");
                return Created("", new
                {
                    Id = createAgent.UsersId,
                    Message = "Agent created Successfully",
                    Status = "Success",
                    UserType = createAgent.UserType
                });
        }
```

And for image uploading code at the API side:

```
private string UploadProfileImage(IFormFile ProfileImage)
        {
            string uniqueFileName = null;
            if (ProfileImage != null)
            {
                string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "ProfileImage");
                uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + ProfileImage.FileName;
                string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    ProfileImage.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
            }
            return uniqueFileName;
        }
```

Comment: Can you send request and get response successfully from postman or other tools?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpClient keeps receiving bad request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37380337/httpclient-keeps-receiving-bad-request)

Comment: If you read the body of the response, does it give any further information on what's wrong with your request?

Comment: How can a client "send a 400 bad response"?  Does not make any sends.  You have a controller.  Controllers can be implemented on either client or server.  When sending a request the following happens.  The GET/POST is the body is the message which is optional.  1) client sends request using POST 2) server receives request using GET 3) server process request 4) server sends response using POST 5) client receives response using GET.  The 400 is generated by the server in step 3 due to the request not being correct.  It is then received in the response by the client.

Comment: This typically means your `agentCreateCto` results in a request that does not match the expected format or data of the endpoint. The response body may include additional error details. We don't know how agentCreateDto looks like and so we don't know how your request looks like. We don't know what data the other side expects and you didn't post the response body with the error messages. That makes it impossible to answer this question. Could you please add those details?

Comment: @jdweng Wouldn't that be a `500 Internal Server Error` on step 3?

Comment: Side note: don't put `HttpClient` in a using block. [read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient#remarks): _"HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors. "_. so make ONE static instantiation.

Comment: Side-note2: You can simplify to `var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync()` (and remove `Wait()` and `.Result` lines.

Comment: @RahulSharma : What is the difference between "Bad Request" and "Internal Error"?  Both are detected in step 3.  "Bad Request" means the server did not like the structure of the request.  "Internal Error" means the server got an error after the  structure of the request was checked.

Comment: From the postman I am able to send and success to get the response. I am sending the Image from the MVC application and the API is receiving [FromForm], is this creating any kind of problem.

Comment: Hi. Let me give some advices. Put debug points on both places (the caller and the API). See if the call even reaches the API and there is some logic error in there. If not, maybe it's a serialization stuff problem. Check the `Output` window of Visual Studio for both cases.

Comment: Total wild guess:  Try `[FromBody]` instead of `[FromForm]` in your `CreateAgent` endpoint.  I can't tell from your question what's causing the response code 400, but `PostAsJsonAsync` makes me think of this.

Comment: Hi,  could you please share your `AgentCreateDto`? Do you add any validation for this model? When I test your code, it posts model data to your api with null value . If you add any validation for this model, it will give 400 bad request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to post file and additional data by HttpClient like below:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44331/api/");
    var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    formContent.Add(new StringContent(agentCreateDto.Id.ToString()), nameof(agentCreateDto.Id));
    formContent.Add(new StringContent(agentCreateDto.Message), nameof(agentCreateDto.Message));
    formContent.Add(new StringContent(agentCreateDto.UserType), nameof(agentCreateDto.UserType));
    //other proerties....
    formContent.Add(new StreamContent(agentCreateDto.ProfileImage.OpenReadStream()), nameof(agentCreateDto.ProfileImage), Path.GetFileName(agentCreateDto.ProfileImage.FileName));

    //change PostAsJsonAsync to PostAsync.....
    var responseTask = client.PostAsync("/Agent/CreateAgent", formContent);
    responseTask.Wait();

    var result = responseTask.Result;
    //more code...
}
```